# Clearing remote desktop user restriction of 2 concurrent users

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, remote-desktop

I am using a Microsoft Azure VM with Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter Edition for developing application with my team. Sometimes there also have to log in some colleagues from db or reporting team. But then we get the default limitation of 2 concurrent users for connecting remotely via remote desktop to the machine.

Is there any way to clear/remove this restriction or set it to a higher value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the RDS role. Install the RDS License Server role. Purchase RDS licenses. Activate your RDS License server. Install RDS licenses.

The default for RDS sessions without the RDS roles and appropriate CAL's is 2 sessions for remote administration purposes. Any attempt to bypass this limitation other than by installing the required roles and purchasing the required licenses is a violation of the EULA and isn't something you'll get help with doing here.

Comment: @joeqerty: I have searched more on that with given infomration and the more information i got i could better search for a solution. What about http://superuser.com/a/631829/647277 and http://serverfault.com/a/618498/351825. Wouldnt this solve my problem?

Comment: Any method that doesn't include installing the RDS role, the RDS licensing role and purchasing the appropriate RDS CAL's is a violation of the EULA. I can't be any more clear on that point. We will provide no assistance in violating the EULA.